# user api to exchange eth token and wallet address creating using code

Tags: cpp-ethereum, exchanges, tokens, encoding

Is there any API to help exchange ether or tokens online which will help in coding an exchange.
For bitcoin one can generate a wallet address, is it possible to generate a wallet address for Ethereum with the help of api?

Comment: You have https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet to create ethereum wallet address programatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your own system as one of the node of ethereum platform, you can download the ethereum wallet from this link: https://www.ethereum.org/

If you want to create accounts on ethereum platform using Java, then you can use web3j.

Java 8:
    
      org.web3j
      core
      3.2.0

If you are not that much tech savvy, then you can simply go to any exchange site which provide Ether transaction and signup.